# IntelliJ IDEA Android make is slow

Tags: android, eclipse, build, intellij-idea, makefile

I recently switched to IDEA as I often had have problems with Eclipse. Overall everything feels great. However, one issue annoys me. Building a simple application take a lot of time. If I change only one line, building takes about 1min. In Eclipse it took about 3 seconds.

I've searched a lot how to improve the performance, but nothing helped. I use the 64 Bit version of IDEA, I increased the RAM, gave the compiler a higher heapsize (Java and Android DX compiler), checked "Make project automatically" and "Compile independent modules in parallel". It didn't change the situation.

Why is Eclipse so much faster in building an .apk than IDEA is? How do you handle this long process?

Comment: It's hard to say anything specific. It could be anything, starting from misbehaving antivirus slowing access to IDEA caches, firewall blocking compiler process communication, incorrectly configured project with unnecessary libraries added to the dependencies or it can be a bug that is triggered by some specific setting in your project. You should contact support with [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446), `build.log` with `info` logging and a sample to reproduce. Disabling **external build** may help, but it's not a recommended solution.

Comment: i'm using IntelliJ 13 and it says this feature (disabling external build) is deprecated and will be removed soon? I wonder why? Enabling it makes the compilation much slower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the antivirus software was causing the issue (ZoneAlarm). Please vote CrazyCoder's comment up, he had the correct intention. Build and launching the app takes about 2 seconds now. Great, really great.